# VBA loop through subfolders to open multiple files

Tags: vba, excel, loops, filesystemobject

I have a code that allows me to search through a file path and multiple subfolders to open a file however I want to be able to open multiple files which have a slightly different name e.g effect00001.dat or effect00014.dat however I'm not too sure how

My code is:

```
Sub LoopSubfoldersAndFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim subfolders As Object
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim CurrFile As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder("\\My Documents\Output files\analysis-tool-development")
    Set subfolders = Folder.subfolders
    MyFile = "effect00001.dat"

    For Each subfolders In subfolders

    Set CurrFile = subfolders.Files

        For Each CurrFile In CurrFile
            If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & MyFile)
            End If
        Next

    Next

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set subfolders = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Most of your questions have no accepted answer. If you want people to help you, you have to do your homework and accept an answer (at least if one is satisfactory)

Comment: try to put the file names in array

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by `For Each CurrFile In CurrFile`. Normally the logic is `for each <object> in  <collection>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the line

```
If CurrFile.Name = MyFile Then
```

by

```
If CurrFile.Name Like MyFile Then
```

You can then use [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) for `MyFile`

---

**Edit:**

I also think the line

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & MyFile)
```

should be replaced by

```
Workbooks.Open(subfolders.Path & "\" & MyFile)
```

since `wb` value is replaced by another one immediately, and not used.

Comment: When I compare the time you have modified and the time I have registered, the time I have answered is fast. Since this is not a very difficult subject, does not everyone have a similar answer?

Comment: When doing this it still only opens the original file and doesn't open any of the rest though @PatrickHonorez

Comment: What changes did you make to this line: `MyFile = "effect00001.dat"`?  As suggested by @PatrickHonorez, please review your other open questions.  [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) rewards the contributor and helps others to find working solutions to their problems.

Comment: I have changed it to MyFile = "effect00***.dat" which opens up the very first file however I want to be able to open multiple files @destination-data

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?  Press F8 to run the code one line at a time.  Hovering the cursor over variables allows you to peek at their values.  Also, you can shorten `effect00***.dat` to `effect00*.dat`, as * = Zero or more characters.

Comment: Would advise against reusing vars for multiple purposes.  This practice makes it hard to understand what each variable does.  Example: `For Each subfolders In subfolders`.  I would replace with `For Each currentSubfolder In subfolders`.  Now you tell one var holds the current subfolder, whilst the other holds the master list.  This can also lead to incredibly confusing errors.  If a var is reset inside a loop which value is checked during the next iteration?  The original value?  The new value?

Comment: I have tried stepping through it and it flashes as in to show its tried to open each file but it only ever opens the very first, do you think I need to state to open the other files in a new worksheet or workbook or something along those lines? @destination-data

Comment: I thought of that too.  But tested and it didn't make any difference.  Try skipping the lines between `With Application...End With`.  It's possible this is suppressing an error message.

Comment: I've tried doing that and its made no difference either, no error message came up @destination-data

Comment: It may be time to move everything into a database.  Both Access or SQL Server would quickly and easily slice through things like this.